# delegate checkbox within my table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
  <td>453</td>
  <td>Nick  James</td>
  <td>12/9/2016</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

JS

```
$('body').on('click','#myTable tbody',function(e){
    alert('do something');
});
```

I have checkbox within my table row, how do I delegate it form above's click event? I do not want the event to be occur when I click on the checkbox.

Comment: could you please explain what you want in here.. Do you want to check the checkbox as the user clicks the table row? Or what?

Comment: so you don't want some one clicking on the checkbox?\

Comment: @wwwDELL I already explain in my last sentence mate.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan when someone click on the checkbox i do not want to click event for the tbody to be occurred.

Comment: @SivaNatalie see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32432363/1479535).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform the functionality only when target type is not checkbox

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('body').on('click','#myTable tbody',function(e){
if(e.target.type!='checkbox')
    alert('do something');
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='myTable'>
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
  <td>453</td>
  <td>Nick  James</td>
  <td>12/9/2016</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the target is checkbox and prevent further execution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('body').on('click','#myTable tbody',function(e){

        if($(e.target).is(':checkbox'))
        {
            return;
        }

        alert('do something');

    });
})
```

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r96o2n6a/)

Answer (score 0):

Use stop **[event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)** to prevent the click on inner element to bubble across the parents.

```
$('body').on('click','#myTable tbody input[type="checkbox"]',function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$('body').on('click','#myTable tbody',function(e){
    alert('do something');
});
```

Now the alert will come only when you click on anywhere inside the table, which is not a `input[type="checkbox"]`.

Comment: OP said **when someone click on the checkbox i do not want to click event for the tbody to be occurred.**

Answer (score 0):

try this

You can use Jquery [**not**](http://api.jquery.com/not/) and [**has**](https://api.jquery.com/has/) selectors to achieve this

```
$('body').on('click','#myTable tbody td:not("td:has(input[type=checkbox])")',function(event){
   alert('do something');
});
```

Working [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/2a3p05mm/)